# Table data to json . MSSQL

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I need to convert table data to Json,
NOTE: i know we can do it easily with the help of Json path like below code

```
SELECT
    divisionId
    ,Divisionname
    ,isActive
    ,Divcode
FROM [dbo].[Division]
    FOR JSON PATH, 
        INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
GO
```

But my task is to do same operation with cursor
I wrote cursor its working fine
but how to append Json each time loop rotate

```
DECLARE
    @divisionId INT,
    @Divisionname varchar(50),
    @isActive bit,
    @Divcode int

DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR
    FOR SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Division]
    --WHERE PlantTypeId=2;

OPEN cursor1;
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO  @divisionId,@Divisionname,@isActive,@Divcode
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN
        --PRINT  cast(@divisionId as varchar)+','+ @Divisionname +','+ cast(@isActive as varchar)+','+@Divcode

       PRINT concat( @divisionId,@Divisionname,@isActive,@Divcode)
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursor1 INTO 
            @divisionId,@Divisionname,@isActive,@Divcode
    END;

CLOSE cursor1;
DEALLOCATE cursor1;
```

o/p of courser look like this

```
2PH110
15AH113
16WF014
17BC115

Completion time: 2022-08-03T16:34:09.1279503+05:30
```

instead of Print I should implement Json

Comment: Cursor is almost always the worst possible way to accomplish a task. The BEST way to do this is to just return the data, and let the client code or reporting tool create the json.

Comment: I know it's a bad way to do it.. but it's my assigned task I should do like that way